# Looking for fun and illuminating weather visualizations

Tags: meteorology, wind, weather-forecasting, visualization, weather-satellites

I'm looking for illuminating and fun weather data visualizations like e.g. [EarthWindMap](https://earth.nullschool.net).

More specifically, I was hoping to find wind vectors overlayed onto a prognostic chart to visualize how the wind moves around pressure systems and fronts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Windy.com](http://www.windy.com/)  It looks very similar to the EarthWindMap, but appears to offer more controls.  It is simple to change the heights and what variables are of interest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [VentuSky](http://www.ventusky.com). An interactive map with different models and data visualization that can be adjusted easily.